# Can I hack people connecting to my server?

Tags: networking, server

First of all, this is obviously for learning porpoises only. Don't be afraid to answer.
So anyway, is there a way for a man to hack a computer logging in, for example, to a garry's mod server hosted on my PC?
If there is, I am very interested on how this is working. Explanations will be welcome.

Comment: _'learning porpoises'_ - would that be a school of dolphins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, yes, it's possible. Game clients receive data from their servers, which they expect to be in a particular format. If the server is modified to send mis-formatted data, the result could easily be to trigger a buffer overflow or other exploitable bug in the client.

See for example http://threatpost.com/researchers-discover-dozens-of-gaming-client-and-server-vulnerabilities/100744

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your locale, but most countries have a similar law to the UK's Computer Misuse Act. Which pretty much means 'hacking back' is illegal.

If you want to learn about exploits, and how to use them ethically - www.google.com is the place to start, try looking for 'ethical hacking course'